# In python when I use or operator doesn't show error nor my expected result

Tags: python-3.x

```py
command = input("what is harder to catch the faster you run? ")
ans = command.split(" ")

if "breath" or "air" in ans:
     print("you're smart")
else:
     print("sorry, you're wrong")
```

I'm not getting the expected result. The output is always:

```
print("you're smart")
```

Comment: This should answer your question: [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't work is because `or` is checking the truthiness of the two statements, it doesn't work to compare multiple values, only to `OR` multiple booleans. So what you really have is

```
if ("breath") or (("air" in ans) == True):
```

Specifically, this is not checking if `"breath"` is in `ans`, but instead checking `if breath:`. More on that at the bottom of the answer.

You can check if both values are in `ans` by writing out the `in ans` part twice, like this:

```
if "breath" in ans or "air" in ans:
```

or if you think you will wind up checking a ton of values, you can do a list like the other answer mentioned:

```
wordlist = ["breath", "air", ...]
contains_word = False
for word in wordlist:
  if word in ans:
    contains_word = True
    break
if contains_word:
  #do stuff
```

Note: "`breath`" is being evaluated for truthiness by the `or`. In python, non-empty strings are "truthy", and empty strings are "falsy". If you do `"breath"==True` then you would get `False`, but if you do `if "breath":` , then the `if` statement would evaluate as `True`. Whereas `if "":`  would evaluate as `False`.

Comment: `"breath" == True` is always false. Don't confuse truthiness with the boolean value `True`.

Comment: Yup good point. Corrected the error on that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `set.intersection()` shorthand.

```
#if ans is a list - ex ["your", "breath"]
if {"breath", "air"} & {*ans}:
    #do something
```

You could tie it together so all of your questions and answer sets are in lists that you `zip` and loop over.

```
qn = ["What is harder to catch the faster you run? ", ...]
an = [{"breath", "air"}, ...]

for q, a in zip(qn, an):
    ans = input(q).lower().split(" ")
    if a & {*ans}:
        print("You're smart!")
    else:
        print("Sorry, you're wrong.")
```

You could even do `input`, `check` and `print` on one line.

```
qn = ["What is harder to catch the faster you run? ", ...]
an = [{"breath", "air"}, ...]

for q, a in zip(qn, an):
    print("You're smart!" if {*input(q).lower().split(" ")} & a else "Sorry, you're wrong.")
```